# How to compare all values of numpy ndarray and a particular column of data frame to extract corresponding values of another column of that data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy
def get_token(instrument):
    response = requests.get("https://api.kite.trade/instruments")
    var1 = response.content.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in var1.split('\n')])
    df =df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
    mask = df['segment'].isin(['NFO-FUT', 'NFO-OPT'])
    df_filtered = df[mask]
    if (instrument.lower() == "future"):
        df = df_filtered.loc[df_filtered['segment'] == 'NFO-FUT']
    else:
        df = df_filtered.loc[df_filtered['segment'] == 'NFO-OPT']
    df = df.drop(['tick_size', 'last_price'], axis = 1)
    return df.replace('"','', regex=True)

df = get_token("Option")
# print(df)
def get_bhavcopy(date):
    date = date.replace("-","")
    try:
        payload=pd.read_csv("https://archives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_"+date+".csv", skipinitialspace = True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return payload
pd.set_option('max_column', None)
price_data= get_bhavcopy("25-06-2021")
mask = price_data['SERIES'].isin(['EQ'])
price_data = price_data[mask]
df_np = df['name'].unique()
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','close'])
```

I am trying to get the ATM strike, and 5 strike above and below ATM.

**What I am doing here is**

1. getting the price of each symbol from NSE
2. getting the strike lists of all F&O

and intend to find ATM strike by getting the strike price closest to the last close price for each symbol.

Therefore I need to compare the each value in **df_np** (a np array) and "SYMBOL" column in **price_data** (dataFrame) to get the last price so that I can use it to find the ATM strike from **df**

I am not sure how to do that!! or if there's any better way to achieve my goal of **finding 10 strike above and below of ATM price for a symbol on a particular day.**

Comment: SYMBOLs are not unique in the `price_data` dataframe, how do choose which last price for a given symbol ?

Comment: SYMBOLs are unique, as I am fetching it from NSE website itself and there can't be two symbols with same name in a given date.

Comment: I ran your code, there are many cases where the same SYMBOL appears several times on 25-06-2021, with different **SERIES**. Try running `price_data['SYMBOL'].value_counts()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out,I missed it as I simply did a "remove duplicate" in excel and it showed me "no duplicates found" (may be I selected wrong column). I have removed the duplicates now by filtering it as per my requirements. @joao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get symbol, last price, and strikes together

First, let's get a proper dataframe with the last price (close) for each symbol: turn `df_np` into its own dataframe, then merge with `price_data` and extract the relevant columns:

```
last_px = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'SYMBOL': df_np}), price_data)[['SYMBOL', 'LAST_PRICE']]
```

On the `df` dataframe, we group strike prices by name, and aggregate by listing, so that we can build a dataframe where each name is associated to a list of strike prices. Also, change 'name' to 'SYMBOL' in preparation for another merge:

```
strikes = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('name')['strike'].agg(list)).reset_index()
strikes.columns = ['SYMBOL', 'strike']
```

Now merge last price and strikes together:

```
df3 = pd.merge(last_px, strikes)
```

Now we have the following dataframe:

```
In [26]: df3
Out[26]: 
         SYMBOL  LAST_PRICE                                             strike
0      AARTIIND      862.10  [1000, 1000, 1010, 1010, 1020, 1020, 1030, 103...
1         ABFRL      222.80  [165, 165, 170, 170, 175, 175, 180, 180, 185, ...
2           ACC     2044.90  [1160, 1160, 1180, 1180, 1200, 1200, 1220, 122...
3      ADANIENT     1516.00  [1000, 1000, 1020, 1020, 1040, 1040, 1060, 106...
4    ADANIPORTS      711.00  [1000, 1000, 1010, 1010, 1020, 1020, 1030, 103...
..          ...         ...                                                ...
155         UPL      803.55  [410, 410, 420, 420, 430, 430, 440, 440, 450, ...
156        VEDL      262.55  [165, 165, 170, 170, 175, 175, 180, 180, 185, ...
157      VOLTAS     1030.00  [1000, 1000, 1020, 1020, 1040, 1040, 1060, 106...
158       WIPRO      546.90  [320, 320, 325, 325, 330, 330, 335, 335, 340, ...
159        ZEEL      218.00  [130, 130, 135, 135, 140, 140, 145, 145, 150, ...

[160 rows x 3 columns]
```

### Find the strikes around the ATM price

Now we're going to apply a function on each row, using the last price and strikes list to determine the ATM price and the 5 strikes above and below. The function turns the strikes list into its own dataframe (with float values), then adds a column that computes the difference with the last price, and the `idxmin` function will tell us where that difference is minimal, i.e. where are we closer to the ATM price. Using `iloc` (and because we reset the index) it's easy to find +/- 5 indices, so we return those values as a list.

Here's the function definition:

```
def around_atm(last_prc, strike_list):
    xdf = pd.DataFrame({'strikes': strike_list}).reset_index(drop=True)
    xdf['strikes'] = xdf['strikes'].astype(float)
    xdf['abs_delta'] = abs(last_prc - xdf['strikes'])
    imin = xdf['abs_delta'].idxmin()
    return xdf.iloc[imin-5:imin+5]['strikes'].tolist()
```

Finally, let's apply this function, putting the results in a new column:

```
df3['above_below'] = df3.apply(lambda x: around_atm(x['LAST_PRICE'], x['strike']), axis=1)
```

The `above_below` column now holds the 5 strike above and below the ATM price:

```
In [30]: df3
Out[30]: 
         SYMBOL  LAST_PRICE  \
0      AARTIIND      862.10   
1         ABFRL      222.80   
2           ACC     2044.90   
3      ADANIENT     1516.00   
4    ADANIPORTS      711.00   
..          ...         ...   
155         UPL      803.55   
156        VEDL      262.55   
157      VOLTAS     1030.00   
158       WIPRO      546.90   
159        ZEEL      218.00   

                                                strike  \
0    [1000, 1000, 1010, 1010, 1020, 1020, 1030, 103...   
1    [165, 165, 170, 170, 175, 175, 180, 180, 185, ...   
2    [1160, 1160, 1180, 1180, 1200, 1200, 1220, 122...   
3    [1000, 1000, 1020, 1020, 1040, 1040, 1060, 106...   
4    [1000, 1000, 1010, 1010, 1020, 1020, 1030, 103...   
..                                                 ...   
155  [410, 410, 420, 420, 430, 430, 440, 440, 450, ...   
156  [165, 165, 170, 170, 175, 175, 180, 180, 185, ...   
157  [1000, 1000, 1020, 1020, 1040, 1040, 1060, 106...   
158  [320, 320, 325, 325, 330, 330, 335, 335, 340, ...   
159  [130, 130, 135, 135, 140, 140, 145, 145, 150, ...   

                                           above_below  
0    [830.0, 840.0, 840.0, 850.0, 850.0, 860.0, 860...  
1    [210.0, 215.0, 215.0, 220.0, 220.0, 225.0, 225...  
2    [1980.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2020.0, 2020.0, 2040....  
3    [1460.0, 1480.0, 1480.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1520....  
4    [680.0, 690.0, 690.0, 700.0, 700.0, 710.0, 710...  
..                                                 ...  
155  [770.0, 780.0, 780.0, 790.0, 790.0, 800.0, 800...  
156  [250.0, 255.0, 255.0, 260.0, 260.0, 265.0, 265...  
157                                                 []  
158  [530.0, 535.0, 535.0, 540.0, 540.0, 545.0, 545...  
159  [205.0, 210.0, 210.0, 215.0, 215.0, 220.0, 220...  

[160 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the hardwork. Can you tell me why values are not coming in the column "above_below" for some symbols?

Comment: It looks like a border condition, when the ATM is too close to either the min or max of the strikes, and there are fewer than 5 strikes on one side. Maybe replace `imin-5` with `max(0, imin-5)`, and something similar for `imin+5`?

Comment: Thanks. that serves the purpose. I am getting one more issue while finding the corresponding instrument tokens for the range of ATM prices (in above_below column). Can you help me with that? I am simply stuck here since day before yesterday.  what I tried was to return the tradingsymbol along with the strike prices found above_below ATM. But again I would have to match them with a different df to find the insturment_tokens, and it seems like a lot of processing. Is there any other way to get to instrument_tokens for the said strikes ?

Comment: I suppose you mean the `instrument_token` column in `df` ? I would add a `couple` column to store the association between token and strike (maybe `df['couple'] = df['instrument_token'].str.cat(df['strike'], sep=' ')` but I'm sure there are other ways), and then use that `couple` column instead of `strike`. Then modify the `around_atm` function to account for the fact that the strike is now inside a couple, so that in the `above_below` is a column of couples (or you can separate the couple). You end up with a row that has symbol, last, token, and strike.